# Bad address with mq_open

Tags: c, posix, ipc

I am trying to open a simple queue using mq_open but I keep getting error:

```
"Error while opening ... 
Bad address: Bad address"
```

And I have no idea why.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct mq_attr attr;
    //max size of a message
    attr.mq_msgsize = MSG_SIZE; 
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    //maximum of messages on queue
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 1024 ;
    dRegister = mq_open("/serverQRegister",O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR,0664, &attr);
    if(dRegister == -1)
    {
        perror("mq_open() failed");
        exit(1);
 }
}
```

I updated code as suggested but still getting error ("invalid argument"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "serverDefinitions.h"
mqd_t dRegister;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct mq_attr attr;
    //setting all attributes to 0
    memset(&attr, 0, sizeof attr);
    //max size of a message
    attr.mq_msgsize = MSG_SIZE;  //MSG_SIZE = 4096
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    //maximum of messages on queue
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 1024;
    dRegister = mq_open("/serverQRegister", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0664, &attr);

    if (dRegister == -1) {
        perror("mq_open() failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might like to replace `printf("Error while opening ... \n"); perror(strerror(errno));` by `perror("mq_open() failed");` and retest. `perror()` appends the "text describtion" for `errno` automagically.

Comment: "Bad address" is `EFAULT`. As per `mq_open()`'s documentation, `EFAULT` is not set by this function.

Comment: @alk I updated the code. Still I am getting "mq_open() failed: Bad address". I am running : Distributor ID: elementary OS
Description: elementary OS Freya
Release: 0.3

Comment: So you want to look up your platform's/implementation's documentation for `mq_open()` on what `EFAULT`  means in this context.

Comment: @alk I run this program on Cloud9 and still get this error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call

```
... = mq_open("/serverQRegister",O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR,0664, &attr);
```

specifies too many parameters. The `mode` seems to have been specified twice.

It should be

```
... = mq_open("/serverQRegister",O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, &attr);
```

or

```
... = mq_open("/serverQRegister",O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0664, &attr);
```

---

Regarding EINVAL, the [`man mq_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html) states:

> **EINVAL**
>
> **O_CREAT** was specified in oflag, and attr was not NULL, but *attr->mq_maxmsg* or *attr->mq_msqsize* was invalid.  Both of these fields must be greater than zero.  In a process that is unprivileged (does not have the **CAP_SYS_RESOURCE** capability), *attr->mq_maxmsg* must be less than or equal to the *msg_max* limit, and *attr->mq_msgsize* must be less than or equal to the msgsize_max limit.  In addition, even in a privileged process, *attr->mq_maxmsg* cannot exceed the **HARD_MAX** limit.  (See mq_overview(7) for details of these limits.)

The initialisation of `attr` hits the limits for either one or both of `mq_maxmsg` or/and `mq_msgsize`. Read [`man 7 mq_overview`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) on how to find out the limits.

Comment: Thank you, but now I am getting "mq_open() failed: Invalid argument". I wrote 'dRegister = mq_open("/serverQRegister",O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0664, &attr);'

Comment: @MarcinMajewski: This most probably dues to missing to initialise `attr` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

mq_open() is a varadic function and it can take either 2 or 4 arguments, but you give it 5, which is wrong.

Make it just

```
dRegister = mq_open("/serverQRegister",O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0664, &attr);
```

Or use the symbolic names, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR instead of the octal representation.

You should also initialize all the members of `attr`, and if you supply the mq_attr, you must set both mq_msgsize and mq_maxmsg, so make it

```
struct mq_attr attr;
memset(&attr, 0, sizeof attr);
//max size of a message
attr.mq_msgsize = MSG_SIZE;
attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
```

(note, mq_maxmsg must be less than what the command `sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max` is set to)

Comment: Still I am getting error, but now it is :"invalid argument"

Comment: Yes, see edit, you need to set mq_maxmsg. Or you can pass NULL as the last argument to mq_open() to use the default attributes.)