# Posix messages Bad adress at mq_open

Tags: c, linux, ipc, mq

## Problem Summary

I am writing a program that is intended to fork multiple processes, each of which open a unique message queue for receiving messages. Every time I run my program, however, every single forked process encounters the `Bad address` error when initializing their respective queues with `mq_open`.

## Some Details

My code is intended to generate message queue names dynamically, following the form `"/_*`, where `*` is some unique letter (a, b, c, etc.) However, upon trying the same code with the string `"/hello"`put in place of the dynamically generated names, the program still failed with the same error.

This has led me to believe that the issue is a failure to create a new queue, rather than an issue with the name itself. However, I believe I am passing O_CREAT correctly, so I can't figure out what the problem is.

I did find [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011979/bad-address-with-mq-open) on the subject, but it doesn't seem that that guy was having the same problems. I believe I have included all relevant code below, but please let me know if more is needed. Any help is much appreciated!

## My code

Here is the wrapper function that actually calls `mq_open`:

```c
mqd_t init_queue(char *desc, long m_flags, long m_max, long m_size)
{
  mqd_t mq_des;
  struct mq_attr attr;
  mode_t mode = 0664;
  attr.mq_maxmsg = m_max;
  attr.mq_msgsize = m_size;
  attr.mq_flags = m_flags;

  if ((mq_des = mq_open(desc, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, mode, attr)) == -1) {
    perror("Error at init_queue");
    exit(1);
  }

  return mq_des;
}
```

Here is the function that calls `init_queue`. I've pasted in the relevant macros and helper function (`nid`) at the top as well, so you can see those:

```c
#define DESCPREF "/_"
#define DESCSIZE 4
#define FIRSTID 97
#define MAXMSGS 200
#define M_SIZE sizeof(struct _message)

char *nid(int id)
{
  char *desc = malloc(sizeof(char) * DESCSIZE);
  char c = id;
  snprintf(desc, DESCSIZE, "%s%c", DESCPREF, c);
  return desc;
}

int node(int id, int inc)
{
  /* INIT */
  proc_info me = malloc(PROCINF_SIZE);
  me->id = id;
  me->curr = id - FIRSTID + 1;
  me->inc = inc;
  char *mypath = nid(id);
  me->listen = init_queue(mypath, O_NONBLOCK, MAXMSGS, M_SIZE);

  /* Do some stuff ... */

  close_queue(me->listen);
  mq_unlink(mypath);
  free(me);
  return 0;
}
```

Finally, the bit of code that forks my individual processes:

```c
int main(){

  pid_t pid;
  int nodes = TESTNODES;

  for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
      perror("Fork error\n");
      exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
      node(FIRSTID + i, nodes);
      exit(0);
    } else {
      printf("Forked: %d\n", (int) pid);
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

## Expected vs. Actual results

I would expect this code to simply run, printing the pids of forked processes, then exit. Instead I get the following errors (for one example run):

```
Forked: 27448
Forked: 27449
Error at init_queue: Bad address
Error at init_queue: Bad address
Forked: 27450
Error at init_queue: Bad address
Forked: 27451
Error at init_queue: Bad address
Forked: 27452
Error at init_queue: Bad address
```

As previously mentioned, I also tried this with the plain string `"/hello"` used as the input name for `mq_open` and received the same set of errors (all five failed in that case as well).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011979/bad-address-with-mq-open might help

Comment: That's the one I linked in my question, unfortunately the problem there was just passing too many arguments to `mq_open`. As far as I can tell that isn't the problem here (though I would be happy to be proven wrong).

Comment: Whoops, didn't click through that, my bad. I'll do some more looking

Comment: The fourth argument to `mq_open()` should be a *pointer to* your attribute structure.  You are instead passing the structure itself.  Add an `&` before its name to produce the needed pointer.  Your compiler *really* ought to be at least warning about that, if not rejecting it altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the pointer to the mq_attr struct like:

```
if ((mq_des = mq_open(desc, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, mode, &attr)) == -1) {
    perror("Error at init_queue");
    exit(1);
}
```

also as per the manual page make sure the values for max messages and msg size make sense otherwise you will get an EINVAL.

```
   EINVAL O_CREAT was specified in oflag, and attr was not NULL, but
          attr->mq_maxmsg or attr->mq_msqsize was invalid.  Both of
          these fields must be greater than zero.  In a process that is
          unprivileged (does not have the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability),
          attr->mq_maxmsg must be less than or equal to the msg_max
          limit, and attr->mq_msgsize must be less than or equal to the
          msgsize_max limit.  In addition, even in a privileged process,
          attr->mq_maxmsg cannot exceed the HARD_MAX limit.  (See
          mq_overview(7) for details of these limits.)
```

Comment: I believe what you're saying is 100% correct, that's what I've seen in all examples online, but when I pass `attr` as `&attr`, my errors change from `Bad address` to `Invalid argument`. How would that be happening? Is this maybe the root of the problem?

Comment: that's why i posted the second part of the answer :) you are hitting limits. try changing your maxmsg to smth small (3 for example) and their size to 1 and you will see.

Comment: ugh, you were right! It was MAXMSGS stupidly set to 200. I kept checking and re-checking the size of my message struct without realizing that it was a too-many message problem. Thank you!!!